# Mongoose how to validate type and value when update/findOneAndUpdate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, schema

I have set up the schema like this.

It works fine on the creation. It will throw validation error if missing required or wrong type. So it will check for both type and value(if i add additional validate function to validate the values on each field)

However, when I try to update or findOneAndUpdate. I have set the runValidators to be true. It works somehow, but it will only validate whether any required missing. But it didn't validate the type and may automatically convert my type to the format.

e.g if i set isAction (expect to be Boolean) to be integer, it will automatically convert into boolean false. So it is kind of bypass the type validation. And then it will enter the validator function which is already boolean but I expect it should throw validation error on the type before enter the validate function

Another concern is on the array and object. It didn't validate the type of deep property in the object and go into the validate function directly.

So I would like to see if there is better way to validate both type and value properly when update/findOneAndUpdate.

I have searched some mongoose validator modules but most of them are helper on the validate function on each field. So those data are already converted from integer to boolean and fail to check the type at that time.

At this moment, I can only think of validate the type and value before insert/update into mongoose.

```js
  const schema = new mongoose.Schema({{
    id: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },
    address: {
      formatted: String,
      streetAddress: String,
      locality: String,
      region: String,
      postalCode: String,
      country: String,
    },
    isActive: Boolean,
  });

const user = mongoose.model('User', schema);

// this one work with the validation on the type
User.create({ id : 'userA' }, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});

// fail to validate the type on both findOneAndUpdate
User.update({ id:'userA'},{ $set: { address:12313 }}, { runValidators: true}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This article https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-version-40-mongoose-nodejs-odm discuss in detail about the mongoose validators.

Please do look on the section **Pre and Post Hooks for Queries**, which lists the  Mongoose 4 feature pre and post hooks for count(),find(), findOne(), findOneAndUpdate(), and update().

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: But the context for pre, post hooks are Model itself. Even though we can get the query but i need to manually check and validate for the data type which I expect the mongoose perform automatically according to the schema defined data type and behave just like create a new one.

If so, why not to perform the validation myself before update the data manually.

btw, thanks for your help.

Comment: I am facing the same issue about checking and validating data type on update. How did you solve this issue? Thank you so much!